# How do I spend ether from an internal transaction?

Tags: internal-transactions

Both etherscan.io and metamask report that the balance of my ethereum wallet does not include the value of any internal transactions. That being the case, how do I "spend" (or send ether) from an internal transaction?

Comment: What do you call an internal transaction ?

Comment: It's the terminology etherscan.io is using. For instance: https://etherscan.io/address/0x3b0bc51ab9de1e5b7b6e34e5b960285805c41736#internaltx