# ETH internal transaction means i received money and it became part of my wallet balance?

Tags: balances, internal-transactions

When someone send a money and it is [shown within internal transactions like here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7aaf70e681f17aae9284dc311431341cb7b64a43#internaltx), then does it mean this money was added to my wallet balance and available for withdrawal same as "normal" transactions money?
You can see that transaction having value of "0.08147364 Ether", but when you click [the transaction for details](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8e160dd491924c685663985954f0a97f50f503b1918950538540b308fe74cbc8), you can see "Value: 0 Ether ($0.00) "

I want to be sure this transaction topped up my wallet money balance and i will be able to [spend this internal transaction money same as normal transaction money](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31420/how-do-i-spend-ether-from-an-internal-transaction).

Answer (score 1):

It means the original transaction was directed at a contract and that contract initiated one or more messages to other contracts and accounts. An example, would be a transaction sent to a contract that is holding funds, instructing it to release funds to your account. Such a transaction might not have any value attached, only instructions, but the funds that arrive in your account are real.

Such transactions are subject to same rules regarding waiting for confirmations before you are *sure*, but by the time you read this, if the funds seem like they are in your account, then you can be confident it is basically irreversible.

[image]

The actual transaction in your example was indeed sent to a contract, and the contract decided to send its own funds to `0x7AaF70e681F17aae9284dC311431341CB7b64A43`.

It's over a day old, so well-confirmed.

In case it isn't clear, contracts run logic when someone sends them a transaction. Among the things they can do is send money where it's supposed to go. Almost everything interesting on Ethereum is a contract. It is probably more technical than you want, but in case it is of interest, the contract can be examined here: https://etherscan.io/address/0xf0cb4ad3b24a5aa73fe1d3604899a2ea86488a75#code. For example, multi-signature wallets and other full-featured/novel-featured wallets are implemented as contracts.

There is nothing obviously suspicious and no economically feasible way to reverse the transaction, so you got paid.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. What is confusing to me is that the contract/transaction has zero value/amount displayed:
[here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8e160dd491924c685663985954f0a97f50f503b1918950538540b308fe74cbc8)
and [here too](https://www.blockchain.com/eth/tx/0x8e160dd491924c685663985954f0a97f50f503b1918950538540b308fe74cbc8)
Blockchain.com conveniently display internal transaction amount on the bottom of the page. I assume i got money when that contract (of the internal transaction that is displayed in my wallet) receive several confirmations..

Comment: That's because the signer was required to send Eth with the instruction to the contract that _it_ should send funds to you. The contract is acting sort of like an escrow. It is commanded to do something. The main thing it wants is a signature from someone authorized to tell it what to do.

Comment: It's doing it's best to show that 0x6cd sent a transaction to 0xf0c and 0xf0c sent funds to 0x7aa. Thanks for accepting my answer.